# neo4j-Gremlin-plugin StackOverflow using tree() pattern

Tags: neo4j, tree, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm trying to perform a tree query over a sample graph. However it always gives me a StackOverflow Exception.
Followed these two doc:

http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#tree-step
https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Tree-Pattern

**To reproduce the error:**

Neo4j 2.3.2 
neo4j-gremlin-plugin 
on: Ubuntu 14.04

**Create the graph:**

`GET http://localhost:7474/tp/gremlin/execute?script=g.addV("Label1").property("name", "Mark").as("v1").addV("Label2").property( "street", "myStreet").as("v2").addV("Label3").property( "number", 11).as("v3").addE("r1").from("v1").to("v2").addE("r2").from("v2").to("v3")`

[image: schermata del 2016-03-17 22 21 15]

**Perorm the query**

`GET http://localhost:7474/tp/gremlin/execute?script=g.V().out("r1").out("r2").tree()`

Neo4j log:

```
2016-03-17 22:13:56.651+0100 INFO  Remote interface ready and available at http://localhost:7474/
2016-03-17 22:22:58.731+0100 ERROR The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._doFindSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1065)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._doFindSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1071)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperTypeChain(TypeFactory.java:1014)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:285)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:862)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:267)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:326)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:212)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:902)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:399)

    [... lines omitted ....]

    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:862)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:267)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:326)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:212)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:902)
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._doFindSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1065)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._doFindSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1071)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperTypeChain(TypeFactory.java:1014)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:285)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:862)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:267)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:326)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:212)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:902)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:399)

    [... lines omitted ....]

    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:862)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:267)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:326)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:212)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:902)
2016-03-17 22:22:59.106+0100 WARN   java.lang.StackOverflowError
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._doFindSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1065)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._doFindSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1071)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperTypeChain(TypeFactory.java:1014)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:285)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:862)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:267)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:326)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:212)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:902)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:399)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:275)

    [... lines omitted ....]
```

Can you help me to dig into this problem?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is a likely a TinkerPop issue: [TINKERPOP-732](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-732) (which was actually a longstanding [Jackson issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/76) that just recently got fixed in 2.7.x) and should be fixed for release 3.1.2.